# LAMP does not save any php logs

Tags: php, logging

I have a brand new vps server with Ubuntu 14.04, i686, Apache 2.4.7, php 5.5.9

here's my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com

DocumentRoot "/home/drake/www/"

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

ErrorLog /home/drake/logs/error.log
CustomLog /home/drake/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**ls -la /home/drake/logs:**

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 29 23:30 .
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 29 23:30 ..
```

I have a php file index.php:

```
<?php
ecoja a3ad
```

I want to test the log files and nothing gets saved.

in my php.ini i have:

```
error_repoting E_ALL
display_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_log = /home/drake/logs/php_error.log
```

Why I dont see any logs?

Comment: What is permission of `/home/drake/logs` directory ?

Comment: @AbhijeetKasurde drwxrwxr-x, but I changed it to 777 and still nothing

Comment: Are you sure you change rights on /home/drake/logs/ because in your question, it is still 775 ? Did you change /home/drake/ rights to 777 ? It s not safe but check it.

Comment: @kranteg I did back and forth ... now it is set at 777

Comment: Another angle - why are you logging into a non-default directory (and document root for that matter)? What's wrong with `/var/log/apache2/drake/*.log` and `/var/www/drake`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Apache Apache/2.4.7 you might need to simply restart the service.

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

You also might create the file manually:

```
touch /home/drake/logs/error.log
```

Change the permissions:

```
chown "MYAPACHEUSER": /home/drake/logs/error.log
```

Make sure the path: `/home/drake/logs` has write access.

```
chmod +rw /home/drake/logs/error.log
```

Also, double check to make sure the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` contains something, maybe they still go there.

Now, if you remove or move the file, you need to restart the service. I recommend `graceful` first.